# cindent, smartindent <esc>=% features in vim

Tags: vim

I like cindent, smartindent and =% features in vim, which properly indents the code.
But, I have one problem with this, it indents everything with 8 spaces, and if I have few nested ifs, it can be very long line like here, though having so many nested ifs in first place is another question.

```
  4 int main()
  5 {
  6         if(x)
  7         {
  8                 if(u)
  9                 {
 10                         if(y)
 11                         {
 12                         }
 13                 }
 14         }
 15 }
```

I tried to set ts=1 and still it doesnt work.

Is there any way to make default indentation level to 4 spaces while using these features?

Edit
set sw=4 solved the problem. No wonder vim always surprises me :)

Comment: If you have so many nested ifs, could it be that you are doing things wrong and testing the normal case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114342/what-are-code-smells-what-is-the-best-way-to-correct-them/223881#223881

Comment: @hlovdal: No i dont have so many ifs, I just wanted way to make it look nice by having less space :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `shiftwidth`, abbreviated `sw`.

Edit: a couple quotes from documentation:

- `shiftwidth`:    Number of spaces to use for each step of (auto)indent.  Used for |'cindent'|, |>>|, |<<|, etc.
- `tabstop`: Number of spaces that a `<Tab>` in the file counts for.
- `expandtab`: In Insert mode: Use the appropriate number of spaces to insert a `<Tab>`. Spaces are used in indents with the '>' and '<' commands and when 'autoindent' is on.
- `smarttab`: When on, a `<Tab>` in front of a line inserts blanks according to 'shiftwidth'.  'tabstop' is used in other places.

Depending on your style, you may have to change more than one of these. Have a look at their help entries if you need more clarification!

Comment: how does sw works for >>, <<. I tried if(1<<3) and cout<<"var"; and it doesnt give any space, am i missing something ?

Comment: It's `>>` when used in normal (or visual) mode, not when typed in insert mode. It indents the current line.

Comment: Note that you can prefix `<<` and `>>` with numbers to indent multiple times, but only when using from Visual mode. In normal mode, the number specifies a number of lines to indent.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `shiftwidth` (`sw`) to 4.

And, if you want to use spaces instead of tabs, `set expandtab` (`et`). Then you can change all those tabs to spaces with `:retab`.